# Whom has Patrick actually killed in “You'll Never Find Me?”

Tags: youll-never-find-me

Near the end of [*You'll Never Find Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27ll_Never_Find_Me_(film)) (2023), we see that Patrick is apparently a serial killer, having murdered many women, with the visitor being his last victim.

However, the end of the movie suggests that some or all of the previous events, even the storm itself, might have been hallucination, so we cannot necessarily take this revelation (or anything Patrick says or believes he hears) at face value. In particular, there are strong suggestions that the visitor might be not real or might be a ghost, and one of the hallucinations that Patrick has suggests that all his victims might be the same person (or does he just see them that way?)

Did Patrick kill multiple people or just one woman (or even just *think* he had killed people or *want* to kill)? And if so, under which circumstances and why?